# How to pass more than one DepartmentId in SP?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to pass more than one `DepartmentId` in SP?

```
Execute spGetEmployeesByGender @DepartmentId =1 , @Gender = 'Male';
```

Comment: Consider a table-valued parameter.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Or make your own value parser inside sp from `varchar` param `'val1;val2;val3'`

Answer (score 0):

please refer to 
[Passing a list/array to an SQL Server stored procedure](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)

Comment: Ouch. I would not recommend using the techniques found in that article. They are all either looping or won't work with any current versions of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys finally I alter the table like this

```
Create Procedure spGetEmployeesByID
@DepartmentId int
as
Begin
  Select Name from tblEmployee Where DepartmentId IN (1 ,  3) 
End

Execute spGetEmployeesByID @DepartmentId = 1
```

Comment: what if you pass in @DepartmentId = 2 ?

Comment: Same Result will be executed , because scalar variable is must